# What is the colored Git tool in Windows command line

Tags: git

In tutorials I see a command line like this:
[image]

What is this? Where can I get it from for both `Windows` and `Mac`?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not `git`. This is `zsh`(especially `oh-my-zsh`). `zsh` is only available for Unix/Linux/Mac/...

Comment: @dan1st ok so oh-my-zsh for Mac.    Is there anything at least similar for Windows?

Comment: You can try to modify powershell(I am unexperienced there) or emulate linux(using WSL or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows : there is the `posh-git` extension for Powershell.

- project is hosted on [github](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)
- the README page details the [installation instructions](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#installation)

You should look for a similar extension for your terminal on MacOS.